# JPA/CriteriaBuilder ignoring decimal part of Double

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to search `foo` by minimum and/or maximum value (they're `Double`)

If I make a GET `baseUrl/foo?minValue=3900.00&maxValue=3900.99` and I have a foo with `value = 3900.63` and `quantity = 1` then repository returns an empty list

JPA seems to be comparing only the integer part of the params, as shown in debug logs:

```
from
    foo foo0_ 
where
    foo0_.value*foo0_.quantity<=3900
    and foo0_.value*foo0_.quantity>=3900
```

Project's structure is:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    // id and other things

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Double value;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class FooResource {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Foo>> findFoos(FooSpecification fooSpec,
        ...
        pagination params
        ...
        @RequestParam(value = "minValue", required = false) Double minValue,
        @RequestParam(value = "maxValue", required = false) Double maxValue) {

        Specification<Foo> newSpec = fooSpec.and(service.getValuesSpecification(minValue, maxValue));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.findAll(newSpec, pagination));
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

    public Page<Foo> findAll(Specification<Foo> spec, PageRequest pagination) {
        return repository.findAll(spec, pagination);
    }

    public Specification<Foo> getValuesSpecification(Double minValue, Double maxValue) {
        Specification<Foo> spec = Specification.where(null);
        if (minValue != null) {
            spec = spec.and(SpecificationHelper.getFooByMinValue(minValue));
        }
        if (maxValue != null) {
            spec = spec.and(SpecificationHelper.getFooByMaxValue(maxValue));
        }
        return spec;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SpecificationHelper {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static Specification<Foo> getFooByMinValue(Double minValue) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            // value is multiplied by quantity
            Expression<Double> totalValue = criteriaBuilder.prod(root.get("value"), root.get("quantity"));
            return criteriaBuilder.ge(totalValue, minValue);
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static Specification<Foo> getFooByMaxValue(Double maxValue) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            // value is multiplied by quantity
            Expression<Double> totalValue = criteriaBuilder.prod(root.get("value"), root.get("quantity"));
            return criteriaBuilder.le(totalValue, maxValue);
        };
    }
}
```

I very appreciate any help

Comment: Im not sure about this but please try ```Expression<Double> totalValue = criteriaBuilder.prod(root.get("value"), root.get("quantity").as(Double.class));```

Comment: Both `criteriaBuilder.prod(root.get("value"), root.get("quantity").as(Double.class));` and `criteriaBuilder.prod(root.get("value"), root.get("quantity")).as(Double.class);` worked! Can you post as answer? Thanks!